# text encoding issues

Tags: c#, xml, flash

I have some xml that contains dodgy encoded characters e.g. Ã¶

how can i convert the xml into a valid format.

a flash app is using the xml file but certain words haved dodgy characters in there.
the flash app need to do various things with the text.

im using c# to generate the xml

Comment: I'm not understanding the flash tag - could you be more specific as to what language / etc?  What attempts have you made so far?

Answer (score 1):

When you see stuff like Ã© or Ã§, it is often the sign you are reading an UTF-8 encoded file (or data) with software thinking it is plain Ascii (or Latin1, etc.).

Just use the right decoder.

Note: it *is* a valid XML format: UTF-8 is even the default encoding of XML, IIRC.